# How to predict a list of models on a list of datasets, within a function?

Tags: r

I'm working on a function that takes as an input a list of dataframes and a list of corresponding models, and runs and sums up the predictions for each. My trouble comes in using the `predict` function itself on a particular model. Because neither the amount nor names of my models are constant, I cannot simply call

```
`predict(model_list$model1, df_list$df1)`
```

for each; instead, I was hoping to loop through each model and predict on each that way. However, when I try to run

```
`predict(model_list[1], df_list[1])`,
```

I run into an error: `Error in eval(expr, envir, enclos) : object 'campaign_type' not found` ("campaign_type" is the first variable in my df).

Indeed, while `summary(model_list$model1)` outputs the full summary of said model, `summary(model_list[1])` only outputs the name, length, class, and mode of the model. I used `caret` to create the models, if that makes a difference. Any ideas here? Again, the goal is to create projections for each model on its corresponding dataframe and sum the projections up, within the function.

Thanks

Comment: Assuming `model_list` and `df_list` are actually lists of models and data.frames, as opposed to just character arrays or simply names, use `[[1]]` instead.

Comment: Wow, well that was a lot simpler than I had imagined...